# How to call chi2pval from my code

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use ‘chi2pval’ function in my code but it’s a private function to stats. How can I make it available to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chi2pval` is a private function that's part of the Stats toolbox.   This function does exist in MATLAB, but you aren't able to call it directly as it's located in a private folder that isn't accessible by you... at least not normally.  What you can do is search for where the source file is located.  You can do that typing in the following command into your Command Prompt:

```
which chi2pval -all
```

[`which`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) determines where a particular MATLAB function you are looking for is located on your machine.  The `-all` flag displays the paths to all functions that you're looking for.  On my Mac OS X machine, this is what I get:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/stats/stats/private/chi2pval.m  % Private to stats
```

You can take a look at the source by invoking `edit` in front of that string that contains the full path to the function, as well as the function name itself:

```
edit /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/stats/stats/private/chi2pval.m
```

When I do this, I see the source code of `chi2pval`.

---

Now, what you can do from here is if you want to actually call `chi2pval`, you can copy the M-file from this directory to where you are calling your main code, then go ahead and run your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You know i did think of that solution, but i thought that maybe Matlab had a better method than coping a function. But it seems not. Thanks

Comment: @user2333346 - I see no other way other than copying the actual function.  MATLAB does not allow you to add private directories to MATLAB's system path to run the function, so the only way that you can run this is to copy the function and place it somewhere else.  Sorry if this wasn't the answer you were looking for, but thank you for accepting it nonetheless!

Comment: No, no. You gave me the answer. I was just hoping something better from Matlab.